# How to determine video codec

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to develop small mac (not iphone) application for self-educational purpose. 
What application should do: just open video file and show information about video codec.

Main problem is that i never work with media files and i don`t now from which point i can start.

May be somebody can advice some articles or may be even examples?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend using something like FFmpeg to get codec information. 
Simply run the following command through NSTask:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg
```

Project page:
http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Extracting this information yourself is a LOT of work.
Every video format stores things different.
 
Not to mention error-handling and corrupted files.

Comment: Thanks, i think it is a best way

Answer (score 0):

The codec data is usually held in container formats. To start you should pick one container format and parse that, a popular one would be the MPEG4 container format. Follow the links from this page to get you started.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14